# Magento 1.9 Override zend lib xml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, zend-framework, lib

I followed this tutorial: https://www.damianculotta.com.ar/magento/bug-en-los-locales-es-en-magento-1-y-2/ which suggested to override this file: src/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/es_419.xml.
I created the new file in this location: features/Multivac_Theme/app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/es_419.xml, but it doesn't work. How can I properly override the file? Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work as expected. Did you flush all the caches ?

Comment: @JulienLoizelet yes, the cache is clean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To alter a locale file without directly editing the library, copy the files to the local code pool and edit the copy:
Make a directory :

```
app/code/local/Zend/Locale/
```

Copy **Data.php** file from :

`lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php`

**To :**

```
app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data.php
```

And Now here you can copy the file which you have to override. 
Like :

```
features/Multivac_Theme/app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/es_419.xml
```

Finally you have to change path In **Data.php**. Replace code from **line 155-159**

```
  $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Data/' . $locale . '.xml';
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("Missing locale file '$filename' for '$locale' locale.");
}
```

**With :**

```
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Data/' . $locale . '.xml';
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $filename = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../lib/Zend/Locale/Data') . '/' . $locale .'.xml';
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("Missing locale file '$filename' for '$locale' locale.");
    }
}
```